# Regex to validate multiple file names in a string

Tags: jquery, regex

I need regular expression to validate multiple file names in a string.

For Example:

`a.html` is valid.
If more than 1 file it should be `a.html;b.html`,
and if more than two it should be `a.html;b.html;c.html`.

Wrong Expression:

```
1)  a;b.html
2)  a.html;b
3)  a;b
4)  a.html;
5)  a.html;b;
6)  a.html;b.html;
```

If the string ends with `;` there should be another valid file name (`c.html`).

My code is:

```
regex": /^([a-zA-Z]:\\)?[^\x00-\x1F"<>\|:\*\?/]+\.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,
alertText": "* Only (;) and (.) are Allowed
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what the regex should match again? I find your wording slightly confusing.

Comment: What counts as a valid filename? What characters are allowed in a name and an extension?

Answer (score 0):

here's a short solution

`/^(?:[^\.;]+\.[^\.;]+)(?:;[^\.;]+\.[^\.;]+)*$/`

some explanations:
the first part `(?:[^\.;]+\.[^\.;]+)` will match a single filename. the filename can be anything without containing `.` and `;`

the secound part `(?:;[^\.;]+\.[^\.;]+)*` is nearby identical to the first, except the `;` in front and the trailing `*`. this represents a filename, like part one, with leading `;`. it will be repeated as much as possible